# routing a different root index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to rails and want to do a simple routing to root operation. My file path is app/views/slots/index.html.erb. When I go in my routes.rb file and see:

```
You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
just remember to delete public/index.html.
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

I change the 'welcome#index' to "slots#index', I get this error from localhost:3000:

```
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

In the terminal, I use ctrl c to exit server and $ rails server to restart and still get the error. I watched my instructor do the same exact simple steps yet I get this error. Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: It seems you did it right. Maybe did you not edit the good file (but a copy) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :** my bad, indeed the error is not corresponding to the solution I described below.

---

It seems you didn't create the `slots` controller.

You have to create a controller to display files. `app/views/slots/index.html.erb` is just a view, corresponding to an action of a controller.

So create the file `app/controller/slots.rb`
    class SlotsController < ApplicationController
      def index
      end
    end

You can do this faster with generator. In your terminal, `cd` to your application path and then
    rails generate controller Slots index

To learn Rails I recommend you some reading here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Doesn't it automatically do that when you create a scaffold? When I started, I used "rails generate scaffold Slot" then the datatypes title:string year:string so on... I have a slots.rb in the models and I dont think my instructor used that command because its not in the instructions. There is a file in controller labeled "slot_controller.rb" is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, scaffolding is OK. As said in my edit I'm wrong, this is not the error message that it would give if no controller. Sorry.

Comment: oh ok Ill have to ask my instructor tonight if no one can see the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. Noob problem to find that the # sign ignores text after. Couldn't add the pound sign in the example above. So it looked fine.